# Index is not valid for indexed component. Parameter with double indexing in pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to create a parameter `Wind_DA` with double index in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po

#DATA
T=3;
W=1;

time = ['t{0}'.format(t+1) for t in range(T)]
wind=['W{0}'.format(w+1) for w in range(W)]

Wind_DA={}
Wind_DA['w1', 't1']=200
Wind_DA['w1', 't2']=200
Wind_DA['w1', 't3']=200

#MODEL
seq=pe.ConcreteModel()

### SETS
seq.W = pe.Set(initialize = wind)
seq.T =pe.Set(initialize = time)

### PARAMETERS

seq.Wind_DA = pe.Param(seq.W, seq.T, initialize = Wind_DA)
```

I am getting the following error:

KeyError: "Index '('w1', 't1')' is not valid for indexed component 'Wind_DA'".

However, when I type on the console `Wind_DA[('w1', 't1')]` I am getting `200`, which means that this dictionary has that index. What could be the problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just a typing error.

When creating the wind array with `wind=['W{0}'.format(w+1) for w in range(W)]`
you're using a capital W, but when creating the param `Wind_DA = {}...` you're using a lower W

Just change `wind=['W{0}'.format(w+1) for w in range(W)]` for a lowercase `w` and that should work properly. `wind=['w{0}'.format(w+1) for w in range(W)]`

```
import pandas as pd
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po

#DATA
T=3
W=1

time = ['t{0}'.format(t+1) for t in range(T)]
wind=['w{0}'.format(w+1) for w in range(W)]

Wind_DA={}
Wind_DA['w1', 't1']=200
Wind_DA['w1', 't2']=200
Wind_DA['w1', 't3']=200

#MODEL
seq=pe.ConcreteModel()

### SETS
seq.W = pe.Set(initialize = wind)
seq.T =pe.Set(initialize = time)

### PARAMETERS
seq.Wind_DA = pe.Param(seq.W, seq.T, initialize = Wind_DA)
```